# Presto - how is there an alternative to to_char like postgresql?

Tags: sql, date, presto, trino

I need to build a query in presto that could look back the trailing 70 days, the table I am working with is storing the dates in the format of 'YYYYMMDD'.

in postgresql, I can just simply write the where clause as

```
where date >= to_char(current_date - 70, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

and it'll pull in the date 70 days ago in a YYYYMMDD format.

However, in PrestoSQL, that function doesn't seem to exist, is there an alternative to this?

Comment: You shouldn't be storing DATE values in a varchar column to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [`date_format()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_format):

```
where date >= date_format(current_date - interval '70' day, '%Y%m%d')
```

Note that storing dates as strings is not a good practice at all - you should be using the proper `date`-like datatype - and then you won't need to do conversions at all.

Answer (score 0):

You would just use date arithmetic:

```
where date >= current_date - interval '70' day
```

I'm not sure why you would want to involve strings in comparisons that are strictly date related.

Comment: I guess OP's `date` column is of type `varchar`.